# WSO2 - Check if an access token is still valid

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am implementing an OAuth 2 token flow using the password grant_type as per the WSO2 docs [here](https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=45944337)

I have this working for logging in users in the web application I am working on currently, and am storing the retrieved access token in local storage.

If I wanted to check the token is still valid (say the user refreshes the browser), is there a request I can make to check access token is still valid and hasn't expired? I assume it would be some form of POST request to the token end point URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To validate the token, there is a admin service which you can use.It's a SOAP service and calling "validate" method in admin service can used to validate the token.

**Validation Endpoint**
https://localhost:9443/services/OAuth2TokenValidationService/

Validate method will respond back to you with validity period. This service is an admin service which you can invoke through basic authentication and other authentication mechanisms such as mutual authentication.

I believe another approach is to call the token endpoint for new token. AFAIR if valid token exist, it's return it with the expiry time which you can calculate the validity period.

Another way is that, if possible you can store the token requested time and have a separate timer to check whether the validity time expired. At the very first time the token generation request make, it's return token with validity period.

Comment: Hmm Ok, is there no end point URL I can just make a request against? I'm not using web services in my application

Answer (score 0):

As harsha89 mentioned you can use the OAuth2TokenValidationService to validate. Sample SOAP request will be like as follows

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:xsd1="http://dto.oauth2.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xsd:validate>
         <xsd:validationReqDTO>
            <xsd1:accessToken>
               <xsd1:identifier>b443652fdc3642bb1b3ba8ebae99068</xsd1:identifier><!--access token received-->
               <xsd1:tokenType>bearer</xsd1:tokenType>
            </xsd1:accessToken>
            <xsd1:context>
               <xsd1:key></xsd1:key>
               <xsd1:value></xsd1:value>
            </xsd1:context>
         </xsd:validationReqDTO>
      </xsd:validate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Sample response

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:validateResponse xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2369:OAuth2TokenValidationResponseDTO" xmlns:ax2369="http://dto.oauth2.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2369:authorizationContextToken xsi:type="ax2369:OAuth2TokenValidationResponseDTO_AuthorizationContextToken">
               <ax2369:tokenString>eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik5tSm1PR1V4TXpabFlqTTJaRFJoTlRabFlUQTFZemRoWlRSaU9XRTBOV0kyTTJKbU9UYzFaQSJ9.eyJodHRwOlwvXC93c28yLm9yZ1wvZ2F0ZXdheVwvYXBwbGljYXRpb25uYW1lIjoiRGVmYXVsdEFwcGxpY2F0aW9uIiwiZXhwIjoxNDQ2Nzg1NjczLCJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbjJAY2FyYm9uLnN1cGVyIiwiaHR0cDpcL1wvd3NvMi5vcmdcL2dhdGV3YXlcL3N1YnNjcmliZXIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3dzbzIub3JnXC9nYXRld2F5IiwiaHR0cDpcL1wvd3NvMi5vcmdcL2dhdGV3YXlcL2VuZHVzZXIiOiJhZG1pbjJAY2FyYm9uLnN1cGVyIiwiaHR0cDpcL1wvd3NvMi5vcmdcL2NsYWltc1wvcm9sZSI6WyJJbnRlcm5hbFwvZXZlcnlvbmUiXSwiaWF0IjoxNDQ2NzgzMjExfQ.VY2J_stNVvCwdGdOn71yw96z0EnbtRabQBt8fDFO5LM4TyNmF56T4uXLGjPW-BaHFKEa21ao0s8zW3UVp3yh2Va5pJhJdEcNeSMHObVvDJBdrDbOqrFZnVG7hxV4n4yIJfWt3jciRQz-SdqVYKJuRF-Tn8qfX30m1s0cMeqEZ2A</ax2369:tokenString>
               <ax2369:tokenType>JWT</ax2369:tokenType>
            </ax2369:authorizationContextToken>
            <ax2369:authorizedUser>admin2@carbon.super</ax2369:authorizedUser>
            <ax2369:errorMsg xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2369:expiryTime>1737</ax2369:expiryTime>
            <ax2369:scope/>
            <ax2369:valid>true</ax2369:valid>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:validateResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hmm Ok, is there no end point URL I can just make a request against? I'm not using web services in my application

Comment: Are you using APIM as the key manager itself or using WSO2 IS or some other identity server as the key manager?

Comment: I believe we are using APIM as the key manager since we are using the identity server on there too - as in I am using user accounts created on there for making token requests with. Is this what you mean? Sorry I'm a bit of newbie to wso2

Comment: I mean have you guys configured wso2-is as the keymanager of wso2-apim. or are you guys using APIM itself as the keymanager

Comment: I have checked and we are using API Manager itself as the key manager